# "Backward" versus "backwards" -- is there any difference?

Tags: differences, adjectives, adverbs

The dictionaries I've looked in don't distinguish between these two words, *backward* and *backwards* (at least when used as adverbs). Is there some real historical, grammatical or regional difference between them?

Comment: Ref. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286/toward-or-towards

Comment: I agree with mmyers: the difference between _backward_ and _backwards_ is the same that exists between _toward_ and _towards_.

Comment: [Is it “backward/forward” or “backwards/forwards”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/109924/65471)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Paul Brians offers this](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/backward.html):

> As an adverb, either word will do:
>   “put the shirt on backward” or “put
>   the shirt on backwards.” However, as
>   an adjective, only “backward” will do:
>   “a backward glance.” When in doubt,
>   use “backward.”

This appears to be from a book "Common Errors in English Usage".

I know that "toward" is considered US and "towards" is considered UK, so this may be the same. (Incidentally I looked in four reference books and didn't find anything about "backward" and "backwards".)

Comment: Thanks; that's useful information. I meant to specify I was only referring to the adverb.

Answer (score 3):

Well there is a very simple difference between backward and backwards.
Backward is used in Ameriacn English ;however, backwards is used in British English.
Example: Travelling **backwards** and forwards between London and New York.- Brit term
or Travelling **backward** and forward between London and New York.-- US term

Answer (score 0):

*Backwards* denotes direction whereas *backward* means *less developed or slow*.