# Can Onwards be used as a sentence?

Tags: expressions

Is "Onwards!" a correct single word sentence meaning "continue" or  "carry on"? Do you know any quotes with it?

Comment: Is [onward](http://www.amazon.com/Onward-Starbucks-Fought-without-Losing/dp/B005X48XN4) close enough?

Comment: Or even [Onwards](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=onwards&newwindow=1&client=safari&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=eOwEU8uTItOM7Ab3w4DwDA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAA&biw=768&bih=927), although it's often paired with "Upwards!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unheard of for *onwards* (or usually, *onward*--see also [*backward* vs. *backwards*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/backward-versus-backwards-is-there-any-difference)) to be used as an interjection, so there's nothing wrong with using it as a single-word command, like "Go!" It's a bit overwrought, though, so I wouldn't recommend using it in formal settings unless you're being intentionally humorous or colloquial.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I can't seem to find any quotes, so I guess it might be used colloquially