# Pluralization: backward and backwards in context

Tags: subjects, grammatical-number

Unless I'm using "backward" and "backwards" wrong, I can pluralize it when the subject is not plural and vice versa.

For example, correct me if I'm wrong:

One movie.

> If you watch your favourite movie
>   backwards, what is the plot?

More than one movie.

> If you watch your favourite movies
>   backward, what are the plots?

I've never stopped to think about this before and am looking for some quick enlightenment as to its validity.

I've seen [this question based on the same words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/backward-and-backwards) but believe it's a slightly different context.

Comment: Also related: [“Toward” or “towards”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286/), [Forward vs Forwards](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/), and especially the top answer to [Afterward versus afterwards](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/).

Answer (score 4):

The *-s* in *backwards* is not a plural suffix, but rather an adverbial suffix, originating in the adverbial use of the genitive case (the genitive case is the origin of modern possessive *'s*). So there is no relation between *backwards* and plural nouns.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no difference, except that certain idioms (like *bend over backwards*) call for one or the other.  [Dictionary.com agrees](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/backwards?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic).  In some areas/dialects/social groups one will be used over the other, but they're basically synonyms at this point.