# "Onward" vs "Onwards"

Tags: word-usage, differences, synonyms, orthography, ward-wards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Toward” or “towards”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286/toward-or-towards)

Which is the correct usage? "Onwards" or "Onward" ?
For example:

> I would be free any time Tuesday onward.

vs

> I would be free any time Tuesday onward**s**.

Or are both correct/wrong?

The spell checker in my browser says that *onwards* is wrong but I've heard people using it.

*(p.s: Sorry if this question is redundant. I searched here but couldn't find a related question)*

Comment: Related: [“Toward” vs. “towards”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286/), [“Forward” vs. “forwards”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/),  [“Upward” vs. “upwards”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29603/) [“Afterward” vs. “afterwards”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/), [“Backward” versus “backwards”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/).

Comment: There seems to be a "from" missing as in "from Tuesday onward(s)".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Apparently,](http://www.diclib.com/onward/show/en/collinscobuild/23863) there is a slight difference, but only in British English:

> Note: In British English, 'onwards' is an adverb and 'onward' is an adjective. In American English and sometimes in formal British English, 'onward' may also be an adverb.

So, depending on where you are, the difference maybe slight.

However, they both mean the same thing practically, and most people will understand you if you use either anyways

Answer (score 2):

Onwards is an adverb, onward is an adjective in American English as well, although practically everyone will understand you no matter what version you use