# "toward" vs. "towards"

Tags: differences, prepositions, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Toward or towards – what would a native speaker use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/toward-or-towards-what-would-a-native-speaker-use)

Consider the following examples:

> Fighting towards anti corruption.
>
> I am going toward north.
>
> I am going towards north.

Which one is grammatical? And what's the difference?

Comment: No need to shout.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's 'toward' or 'towards', 'north' would normally be preceded by 'the', unless the context were purely navigational. Alternatively, you can say 'northwards'.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/towards), there is no difference, at least not grammatically.

> Although some have tried to discern a semantic distinction between the words toward and towards, the difference is merely dialectal. Towards is the most common form, while toward tends to appear only in American English.

That said, I would urge people to avoid the word, as it is easily misused, especially by non-native speakers.

Usually, there are clearer ways of expressing the sentiment. For example:

1. (As mentioned above) I am headed northwards
2. [We are] fighting against corruption, or fighting for a world without corruption

I cannot think of a sentence where "toward[s]" is a better choice of word.

Comment: @RegDwightBBB: Good catch :)